# Converting and saving an uploaded image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, upload, save, converters

I have the following code...

```
$current_full_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..');
$user_profile_picture_filename = $current_full_path . "/profile_pictures/" . $userid . ".jpg";

$user_profile_picture_submit = $_POST['user_profile_picture_submit'];

if (isset ($user_profile_picture_submit)) {

    $user_profile_image = $_FILES['user_profile_image']['name'];
    $temp_profile_picture = $_FILES['user_profile_image']['tmp_name'];

    $profile_picture_extension_array = explode( ".", $user_profile_image); 
    $profile_picture_extension_case_insensitive = end($profile_picture_extension_array);
    $profile_picture_extension = strtolower($profile_picture_extension_case_insensitive);

    if ($profile_picture_extension == "png") {

        $temp_profile_picture_converted = imagecreatefrompng($temp_profile_picture);

    } elseif ($profile_picture_extension == "bmp") {

        $temp_profile_picture_converted = imagecreatefromwbmp($temp_profile_picture);

    } elseif ($profile_picture_extension == "gif") {

        $temp_profile_picture_converted = imagecreatefromgif($temp_profile_picture);

    } elseif (($profile_picture_extension == "jpg") || ($profile_picture_extension == "jpeg")) {

        $temp_profile_picture_converted = imagecreatefromjpeg($temp_profile_picture);

    } 

    imagejpeg($temp_profile_picture_converted, $user_profile_picture_filename, '75');
    imagedestroy($temp_profile_picture_converted);


}
```

What I'm trying to do is get the uploaded picture, get the extension, check which extension it has, then based on the extension, convert it to jpeg with PHP, then save it as the userid.jpg in the "/bar/" directory. However, nothing is saved.

Comment: I think you need to give full path to variable $user_profile_picture_filename

Comment: Full path meaning? Isn't that a  full path? That variable in a situation where $userid is defined would have a value of "http://111.111.1.111/foo/bar/111111.jpg"

Comment: Set your $user_profile_picture_filename path through my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I get solution to convert and save image using php.You can follow this
http://www.kingpabel.com/php-image-resize/

Answer (score 0):

PHP < 5.3

```
$fullpath = dirname(__FILE__);
```

PHP >= 5.3

```
$fullpath = __DIR__;
```

Have a look at [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why this would be applicable. Those predefined constants are simply pointing to the directory of the current file that is being run if I understand correctly.

Comment: You need to save your image using those full path.

Comment: Do you have the permissions to write image ?

Comment: I wrote an uploader for regular files which seemed to work fine on the same server, so yes.

Comment: Thats ok but you need to have permissions to write in that particular folder, check permissions for profile_pictures folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77497/discussion-between-tiger-and-allenph).

Answer (score 0):

This is more robust for getting the file type.

Once you have the raw image convert it and save it.

**Get Upload:**

```
if( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']) || !($_FILES['image1']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)){
  $save = false;
```

**Find type:**

```
  switch(strtolower($_FILES['image1']['type'])){
  case 'image/jpeg':
    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/png':
    $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/gif':
    $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  default:
    $img = getimagesize($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    switch(strtolower($img['mime'])){
    case 'image/jpeg':
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/png':
      $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/gif':
      $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    default:
      $filename = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
      $ext = substr($filename,-3);
      switch(strtolower($ext)){
      case 'jpg':
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'gif':
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'png':
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      default:
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Convert Image to jpg:**

```
 if ($save === true){
   ob_start();
   imagejpeg($image, NULL, 70);
   $jpg = ob_get_clean();
```

**Save:**

Where `$user` is the userid.

```
   $fp = fopen("/home/user/public_html/bar/$user.jpg",'w');
   fwrite($fp,$jpg);
   fclose($fp);
 }
```

}